# How do I create a function that accepts an iterator of i32s as either values or references and sums them?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to have a single function that accepts an iterator to either values or references? If not, is there a way to rewrite one or both of the tests so that they can both call the same `mean` function?

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_mean_of_references() {
        let array = [47, 48, 49];
        assert_eq!(47.5, super::mean_of_references(46, &mut array.iter()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_mean_of_values() {
        let array = [46, 47, 48];
        let mut iter = array.iter().map(|x| x + 1);
        assert_eq!(47.5, super::mean_of_values(46, &mut iter));
    }
}

pub fn mean_of_values(x: i32, xs: &mut std::iter::Iterator<Item = i32>) -> f64 {
    let (sum, len) = xs.fold((x, 1), |acc, x| (acc.0 + x, acc.1 + 1));
    f64::from(sum) / f64::from(len)
}

pub fn mean_of_references(x: i32, xs: &mut std::iter::Iterator<Item = &i32>) -> f64 {
    let (sum, len) = xs.fold((x, 1), |acc, x| (acc.0 + x, acc.1 + 1));
    f64::from(sum) / f64::from(len)
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about [generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-00-generics.html) yet? If yes, why  can't you make them work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare that you will take a generic iterator that yields values which can be added to an `i32` and will return an `i32`:

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub fn mean<I>(x: i32, xs: I) -> f64
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    i32: Add<I::Item, Output = i32>,
{
    let (sum, len) = xs.into_iter().fold((x, 1u32), |acc, x| (acc.0 + x, acc.1 + 1));
    f64::from(sum) / f64::from(len)
}
```

For enhanced fun, it takes in something implementing `IntoIterator`, which means that call sites can be changed to

```
super::mean(46, &array)
super::mean(46, iter)
```