# How to write a generic function taking any iterator of `u32` or `&u32`?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write a function that processes a sequence of integers.

```
fn process_one(n: u32) {}

fn process<II>(ii: II)
where
    II: IntoIterator<Item = u32>,
{
    for n in ii {
        process_one(n);
    }
}
```

I want the client to be able to pass a `Vec<u32>` without consuming it (`process(&v)`). This function can't be used because `<&Vec<u32> as IntoIterator>::Item` is `&u32`; I'd have to pass `v.iter().cloned()` instead, which is annoying.

Alternatively, I could make the bound `Item = &u32` and use `process_one(*n)`, but then I have the reverse problem.

I'm trying to think of a way to write this generically, but I can't figure out how. As far as I can tell, none of `AsRef`, `Borrow`, `ToOwned`, or `Deref` work.

What I need is a way to write this:

```
fn process<II>(ii: II)
where
    II: IntoIterator<Item = MAGIC>, /* MORE MAGIC */
{
    for n in ii {
        process_one(MAGIC(n));
    }
}
```

so that all of these compile:

```
fn test() {
    let v: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    process(&v);
    process(v);
    process(1..10);
}
```

I know I can do this using a custom trait, but I feel like there should be a way without all that boilerplate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a function that accepts an iterator of i32s as either values or references and sums them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288670/how-do-i-create-a-function-that-accepts-an-iterator-of-i32s-as-either-values-or)

Comment: The question is similar, but the key difference is that the person there just wants to sum things up and `Add` is implemented for references, while I need to pass the value on to a function that simply takes an `u32`.

Comment: If you take things by value, this is a consuming iterator. Thus in order to consume a vector, you must own it, not borrow it. You have incompatible requirements.

Comment: @Boiethios I want the function to be agnostic to consuming or not consuming the sequence.

Comment: @SebastianRedl ah, ok; I'll retract my close vote, but you may want to adjust the question so that it doesn't come back from someone else :).

Comment: Ah, I understand: the problem is in `process_one`... But the question is still unclear for me.

Comment: @Boiethios Is it clearer now what I want? Note that I can't change `process_one`.

Comment: You do not have to own the vector, because `u32` can be cloned, so why do you not write: `fn process(slice: &[u32])`? Furthermore, there is no overhead when cloning an `u32`. If the user does not want his vector anymore after that, he does not have to use it.

Comment: @Boiethios That wouldn't work with other iterables, e.g. a range `1..42u32`, which is `IntoIterator<Item=u32>`. I'm also not worried about performance overhead, I'm worried about syntactic overhead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) works:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
    process(x.iter());
    process(x);
    process(1..3);
}

fn process_one(n: u32) {
    println!("{}", n)
}

fn process<I>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<u32>,
{
    for x in iter {
        process_one(*x.borrow());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it with a custom trait.

```
trait ToValue<V> {
    fn to_value(self) -> V;
}

impl<T> ToValue<T> for T {
    fn to_value(self) -> T {
        self
    }
}

impl<'a, T> ToValue<T> for &'a T
where
    T: Copy,
{
    fn to_value(self) -> T {
        *self
    }
}

fn process<N, II>(ii: II)
where
    II: IntoIterator<Item = N>,
    N: ToValue<u32>,
{
    for n in ii {
        process_one(n.to_value());
    }
}
```

While this solves my problem, it leaves me rather unsatisfied, and I still think there should be a solution that doesn't involve my own trait.

Comment: It would be useful if compiler had exposed automatic dereference functionality. Something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b3f7edd5890c61f5b0a24a9968158b73&version=stable)

Comment: This is essentially `ToOwned` but limited to `Copy` types, right?

Comment: Yes, but `ToOwned` has an internal `type Owned: Borrow<Self>` requirement, which made it impossible to use for me.